# android scale groupview by drag

Tags: android, layout, scaling, drag

In my application i have a screen which contains a LinearLayout and a ListView below it.
I need to let the user an option to change the size of the ListView, on the screen, by dragging the list over the LinearLayout as much as he/she needs.
the tabs and the green header are not parts of the screen.

[image: The screen]

How it can be done?

Comment: Add your xml to the question for a start.

Comment: The layout xml based on RelativeLayout which contains to components: LinearLayout and ListView below it. The LinearLayout's heights is wrap_content as the ListView's height.